# Why is dns.lookup working on these incorrect URLs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently trying to create a URL shortening microservice with Node.js. I'm passing in incorrect strings to `dns.lookup()` to check if they are valid URL's, however instead of returning an error, they are returning an address and a family.

```
dns.lookup('hello', (err, address, family) => {
                if(err) {
                    res.send('invalid')
                    return
                } else {
                    console.log(`error = ${err}`)
                    console.log(`address = ${address}`)
                    console.log(`family = ${family}`)
                    next()
                }
            });
```

Console:

```
error = null
address = 92.242.132.24
family = 4
```

I'd like it to pass an error if the URL is invalid.

EDIT: Adding full code if that helps?

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var cors = require('cors')
var dns = require('dns')

            dns.lookup('hello', (err, address, family) => {     
                if(err) {
                    console.log(`error = ${err}`)
                    //res.send('invalid')
                    //return
                } else {
                    console.log(`error = ${err}`)
                    console.log(`address = ${address}`)
                    console.log(`family = ${family}`)
                    //next()
                }
            });

var listener = app.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('working on port 3001')
});
```

Comment: Seeing the function invocation is nice and all, but how about showing the function definition?

Comment: i am getting Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND hello
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'hello'
}

Comment: Thanks Ashish, I was getting your response a while ago, but it's now returning the ip above and I don't know why. The ip is for something called 'Barefruit Ltd.' in London.

https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/92.242.132.24

So weird!

Comment: JDunken, not sure what you mean by this? I've put the rest of my code in an edit above.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my ISP (Virgin Media) has a third party called Barefruit Ltd that intercepts dns errors and sends back advertising instead: https://www.barefruit.com/

For the meantime, I've found a workaround by adding `if(err || address == '92.242.132.24')` to my error handling.